# How can I reset a Tauri app's notification permission on macOS?

Tags: macos, tauri

I tried to use the notification API for Tauri app on macOS.
https://tauri.studio/docs/api/js/modules/notification/

I pressed the deny button when requesting notification permission for testing. And of course, it always returns 'denied' now.

I want to know how I can reset the permission or ask for notification permission again. I tried to look for the notification setting on "System Preferences > Notifications & Focus" and "Safari > Preferences > Security". But I couldn't.

```js
import { notification } from "@tauri-apps/api";

async function testSendNotification() {
    const permission = await notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === "granted") {
        notification.sendNotification("Notification Demo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset it by deleting the `.tauri-settings` file.
On macOS you can find it here:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/your-bundle-id/.tauri-settings
```

If you want to delete it with JavaScript you could try something like this after changing the allowlist accordingly:

```js
import { fs, path } from "@tauri-apps/api";
fs.removeFile(".tauri-settings", { dir: path.BaseDirectory.App });
```

Edit: We removed the custom permission dialog with `1.0.0-rc.15`, and therefore solely rely on the system's built-in settings now.